# Possible for Javascript to callback/signal Selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, selenium

Let's say we're using Selenium on a web page which implements an AJAX request which dynamically populates content within a specific element, `#content`.

`#content` always contains 5 children, none of which contain classes, ids, or any other attributes or unique identifiers. On a random time interval (between 1ms and 10,000ms,) an AJAX request will fire, re-populating the text within each of the five elements, without actually removing the elements themselves.

How would one go about setting up a callback or signal which could communicate back to the application outside of the web browser, that an AJAX request has been fired, and finished... At which point we can now look up the new values?

I have set up the example web site scenario at: http://joshburns.me/js-test/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a waiting loop in python that actively checks for javascript to be idle. And then operate:

Your function for waiting for Javascript to finish (once called it will only return when the javascript is not running on the document):

```
    def waitForJavaScript(browser):
      while True:
        if(browser.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
          return
```